# Use bibentry to produce references in CV without bibliography list: works but error

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, cv, resume, bibentry

The following sample works for me, with res.cls and using pdflatex, bibtex and 2xpdflatex; however, it gives the error `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.` Is this something that can be avoided, or is it related to my own latex version?

```
\let\latexnofiles\nofiles
\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdftitle={zzz}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\nobibliography{mybiblio.bib}
\begin{resume}
\section{abc}
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{some item}
\end{itemize}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Note that it is not related to the res class, as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,pdftitle={zzz}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\nobibliography{mybiblio.bib}
\section{abc}
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{someitem}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

gives the same error

Comment: @egreg note that the warning i get is different, moreover it works ok with hyperref and bibentry, as long as i use the command \nobibliography* and not \nobibliography{..}

Comment: @jj_p Indeed, the problem is having `bibentry` without `natbib`, which is needed if `hyperref` is loaded, see the question I marked this one a duplicate of.

Comment: @egreg thanks, if i add a line \usepackage{natbib} everything goes smooth without errors